# Why date picker is not appearing when click the placeholder name?

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to show the ionic date picker when I click string. But instead of that date picker is showing in the page without clicking anything

here is the [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-viaqmf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

here is my code :

```
<ion-datetime placeholder="pick the date"></ion-datetime>
```

in TS file I just use above code. I wanted to see the date picker when i click the "pick the date " string

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap an ion-input or ion-button in ion-datetime.

something like that:

```
<!-- Datetime in overlay -->
<ion-button id="open-modal">Open Datetime Modal</ion-button>
<ion-modal trigger="open-modal">
  <ng-template>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-datetime></ion-datetime>
    </ion-content>
  </ng-template>
</ion-modal>
```

more in the documentation:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime